# Is there a feature similar to IntelliJ's ALT+J in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-2022, jetbrains-ide

In IntelliJ Idea and other JetBrains IDEs, you can select a word, say an "if", and by pressing ALT+J it will select other occurrences of that same word within that file. Is there anything like that in Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: From the top answer to the linked duplicate: It's Shift + Alt + <dot>.